# question on find value in array

Tags: algorithm

i have seen a few days ago such problem

```
there is given two array find      elements which are common   of these array
```

one of the solution  was  sort  big array and then use binary search algorithm
and also  there is another algorithm- brute-force  algorithm

```
 for (int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
 if (array1[i]==array2[j]){
//code here
}
}
```

it's complexity is  O(array1.length*array2.length);
  and i am interested    the first method's complexity is also     same yes?
because  we should sort array first and then use search method
binary search algorithm's complexity is log_2(n)    so it means that  total time will be
array.length*log_2(n)  and about sort?
please explain me which is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### An `O(M log N)` solution

Let the length of `arr1` be `O(M)`, and the length of `arr2` be `O(N)`. The sort/binary search algorithm is `O(M log N)`.

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
SORT(arr2)   # N log N

FOR EACH element x OF arr1             # M
   IF binarySearch(x, arr2) is FOUND   # log N
       DECLARE DUP x
```

`O(M log N)` is *vastly* better than `O(MN)`.

---

#### A linear-time solution

There's also a third way which is `O(M+N)`, using a set that has a `O(1)` insertion and test. A hash-based set meets this expectation.

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
INIT arr1set AS emptySet

FOR EACH element x OF arr1    # M
   INSERT x INTO arr1set      # 1

FOR EACH element x OF arr2    # N
   IF arr1set CONTAINS x      # 1
      DECLARE DUP x
```

Comment: That's not entirely right. First of all you don't have to sort both arrays and second the lengths of the two arrays need not be equal.

Comment: @IVlad: ok, made the adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is better. If you sort `array1`, the complexity of the first method is `O(array1.length*log(array1.length) + array2.length*log(array1.length))`, because first you sort the first array (in `O(array1.length*log(array1.length))`), and then for each element in the second array, you binary search it in the first array (in `O(array2.length*log(array1.length)`).

Answer (score 0):

Complexity of the first solution will be:

```
sort_complexity(longer_array) + smaller_array.length*log_2(longer_array.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option to use an additional data structure, then using a hash would help you like this: push all elements of the first array into hash. Iterate over second array and check the presence of each element. If it is present in the hash --> it is common for both arrays.